# Firefox and Compiz Ring Switcher Issue

Tags: firefox, compiz

I have a really strange issue where I cannot view the previews of Firefox in the compiz ring switcher because I have the Firefox logo blocking the previews as shown below:

[image]

Is this a change with recent versions of Firefox, or have I somehow messed things up?

Comment: Well that's certainly an.... interesting... bug :D

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a side-effect of the paper icon set  that I had installed from an article on [It's Foss](https://itsfoss.com/install-paper-theme-linux/). Obviously it would be nice if someone could post a workaround for this, but for now I am just going to stop using that icon set.

Comment: Try switch to numix theme, or enable paper theme to use together with paper icon set.

Comment: Using the paper theme with the paper icons has the same effect. I can use the paper theme, just not the paper icon set.